# Change datetime into integer

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Python in dynamo and I am facing a problem.

1. I have to convert date time into integer so I could further process
   it
2. I have tried some codes but they are not helpful.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by datetime as integer? Do you mean like a unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to convert the datetime to a unix timestamp (number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970), then you can do

```py
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> ts = dt.datetime.now()
>>> print(int(ts.timestamp())
1588967243
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to get timestamp?

```
import time
import datetime
s = "01/12/2011"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
```

Result: `1322697600.0`